# Определить, является ли символ в строке латинским

Tags: c#, строки

С клавиатуры вводится строка на кириллице, нужно проверить, нет ли среди символов этой строки символа на латинице. Каким образом можно сделать такую проверку?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            string res = "Нет";
            foreach(char ch in str)
            {
                if((int)ch>=97&&(int)ch<=122)
                {
                    res = "Есть";
                }
            }
            Console.Write(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stepan Kurennyh, а подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть коды символов, если делать аналогичную проверку, но только на вхождение киррилического символа?

Comment: Таблица Unicode

Comment: вот я смотрю здесь http://unicode-table.com/ru/, но не могу разобраться. как соотнести значения из этой таблицы со значениями в вашем коде.

Comment: Номер в юникоде представлен в 16 ричной системе счисления, его можно перевести в 10 ричную, например, стандартным калькулятором windows либо использовать напрямую, например, if ((int)ch >= 0x0061 && (int)ch <= 0x007A).

Comment: а вот в этой строке if((int)ch>=97&&(int)ch<=122), если мы опеределяем, попадает ли символ в промежуток, не & нужен между проверками?