# Запрет ввода русских символов

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Как сделать что-бы в textbox можно было ввести только английские буквы и цифры?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы запретить ввод каких-либо символов сделайте фильтрацию ввода при обработке события `PreviewTextInput`.

Ниже приведён пример того как с помощью данного события можно разрешить ввод в `textBox` только для цифр.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !(Char.IsDigit(e.Text, 0))
}
```

Для того чтобы его доработать под Вашу задачу достаточно добавить проверку, является ли вводимый символ латинским. Пример такой проверки можно посмотреть в этом вопросе: "[Определить, является ли символ в строке латинским](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238848/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC)".

Comment: через `CTRL+V` можно вставить что угодно, как это можно обойти не запрещая комбинации клавиш?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно это не ререшение, но как способ, то при выполнении эвента `textChanged`, или того, что ты задашь, который вызывается при введении текста, то при вводе символа, берешь весь `string`, выбераешь последний символ и смотришь, есть ли он в диапазоне

```
if(ch <='я' && ch>='а' || ch>='A' && ch<='Я')
textBox.Text.Remove(textBox.Text.Lenght-1);
```

Как-то так, только, возможно, я с методами ошибся, так что исправь.

Возможной проблемой этого может стать то, что при вводе кириллицы, она появиться в `textBox`, но после этого сразу же пропадет.
В крайнем случае при коммите действия связаного с `textBox`, ты можешь создать `StringBuilder`, пройтись по символах, ну и если есть хоть один, то выдавать `MessageBox` с ошибкой.